# XSD - Multiple type content validation

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

i want to validate an xml file of the Structure:

```
<element>255</element> <!-- Integers are allowed from 0 to 255 -->
<element>Impossible</element> <!-- "Impossible" should be the only valid string -->
```

is this even possible with xsd? (Without using the string-pattern-matching for the integers)

Best regards

Hemeroc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **union** of integer and restricting string types. [Look at this article](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_union.asp) for example.